# awk and sum rows for large files

Tags: file, if-statement, awk

I have hundred of files to process. Each file contains millions of rows.

Sample file content:

```
---------------
12
3
5
---------------
8
0
5
---------------
1
5
56
4
---------------
```

I need to have the output which looks like below (sum of numbers separated by dashes from previous file):

```
20
13
66
```

I used `while`, `if`, `else` in conjunction with `awk` but `if`/`else` dramatically slows down the processing.

Any ideas how to use pure `awk` to speed up calculations?

Comment: You should show your code — is the `while` and `if` in shell script or in the `awk` script?  There's no need for loops or `if` conditions in the `awk` script, anyway.  Could a file end without a final line of dashes?

Comment: wrt `I used while, if, else` - read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and a shell tutorial. Also get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Is the sample file content representative of a _single_ or _multiple_ files?

Answer (score 3):

you don't need if/else blocks,

```
$ awk 'FNR>1 && /^----/ {print sum; sum=0; next} {sum+=$1}' file{1,2} 
20
13
66
20
13
66
```

for example for the copy of your input file1 and file2.  Perhaps you'll run them one at a time or for multiple inputs a prefix before the sums, for example

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{block=0} FNR>1 && /^----/ {print FILENAME, ++block, sum; sum=0; next} 
                                        {sum+=$1}' file{1,2} 

file1 1 20
file1 2 13
file1 3 66
file2 1 20
file2 2 13
file2 3 66
```

Comment: definitely an `awk to the rescue` moment! Good luck to all.

Comment: For the question, these nitpicks aren't directly germane, but for the real world, they might be.  If the last file doesn't end with the line of dashes, then you won't output the last sum.  That's a nuisance to work around.  If one file didn't end with a line of dashes and the next file didn't start with a line of dashes, you'd combine the two sums.  It seems a bit funny to add the first line's row of dashes to `sum` — though `awk` treats it as zero well enough.   But for well formed inputs, it is fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/^-+$/{if (s!="") print s; s=""; next} {s+=$0}' file
20
13
66
```

Note the setting/comparison of s to `""` to handle it differently it if is a summed value of zero vs just initialized to the null string.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative. I'm curious how it stacks up speed-wise

```
awk -v RS='\n-+\n' -F'\n' 'NF {s=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) s+=$i; print s}' file ...
```

Comment: You should mention it's gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all of you spent your time to help me! Your awk examples are incredibly fast comparing to while/if conditions. Thanks for the link also describing the reasons. It appeared that I created the worst version of the code I could write :-/

My version of code which works as well but it's dramatically slow:

```
sum=0
while read line
                do
                if [ "$line" = "---------------" ]; then
                        echo $sum
                        sum=0
                else sum=`echo $line $sum | awk '{print $1 + $2}'`
                fi
done < input_file.txt
```

Thanks again Gurus!

Comment: Not only is it slow, it will corrupt your output given various input values and/or environment settings and/or contents of the directory you run it from. Do not run this on anything that matters. Instead pick one of the solutions you were given and do that. Also you asked `Any ideas how to use pure awk to speed up calculations?` so have a well-deserved downvote for posting your own solution that doesn't even do what you asked for!